# WooCommerce: give user access to downloadable files when the status is on-hold

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Q: I want to have my customer to have access to the downloadable products when the status of his order is 'on-hold'.

When a customer places an order for a downloadable product AND a physical product, I sometimes want to place the order in the on-hold status (by hand). But then the customer can not download the downloadable product.

The grant access is regulated in woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php (2.2)

```
/**
 * Order Status completed - GIVE DOWNLOADABLE PRODUCT ACCESS TO CUSTOMER.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param int $order_id
 */
function wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order_id ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_download_permissions_granted', true ) == 1 ) {
        return; // Only do this once
    }
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( $order && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) && get_option( 'woocommerce_downloads_grant_access_after_payment' ) == 'no' ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() ) {
                $downloads = $_product->get_files();
                foreach ( array_keys( $downloads ) as $download_id ) {
                    wc_downloadable_file_permission( $download_id, $item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'], $order, $item['qty'] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_download_permissions_granted', 1 );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_grant_product_download_permissions', $order_id );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions' );
```

What do I have to change to accomplish this?

14-07-2016 UPDATE

I have paid a coder for helping me out. This is the code where I was looking for. Add this code to your functions.php:

```
function add_onhold_status_to_download_permission($data, $order) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) { return true; }
    return $data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_is_download_permitted', 'add_onhold_status_to_download_permission', 10, 2);
```

Comment: So by hand you can also grant permission to downloadables

Comment: Dear Mujeebu Rahman I do not understand what you mean. As far as I know there is no option in Woocommerce to set for each order-status or a customers can (or can not) download e-books. Or do you know where I can change the settings?

Comment: Please check http://www.hikeforce.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/grant-access.png

Comment: I understand what you mean. But what I need is something different. This 'Grant Access' only works if the order has the status 'processing' or 'completed'. I want to give my customer access when the status is 'on-hold'.

Comment: you can set Grant Access even if order is in On-Hold

Comment: Just what I needed. I created my own status (paid) which on default would not grand download permissions

Comment: I also had to add the line `add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions');` for the downloads to show up in the downloads-table

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to do this, I just contacted Woocommerce support and there is a box to check in Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Downloadable Products called "Grant access to downloadable products after payment", which allows users to access their downloadable products after their purchase.